# Gerar nova imagem centrada em um ponto

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Eu fiz um processamento e encontrei um ponto na imagem que satisfaz meus critérios. Preciso cortar a imagem original em uma menor (120x120) que tenha como centro esse ponto. Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
mx = pegarPontox()
my = pegarPontoy()
novaImagem = img[mx-60:mx+60][my-60:my+60]
```

Porém, ele me retorna uma lista vazia. Como faço esse recorte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Busquei no SO em inglês e vi que meu `slice` no array estava errado, eu faço o seguinte:

`array[inicio:fim][incio:fim]`

Porém o correto seria assim:

`array[inicio:fim, inicio:fim]`

A ideia do `crop` na imagem está correta mas a minha aplicação foi falha.